# Changing the style of a glossary

Tags: glossaries

Using the `glossaries` package, I almost get the result I want, loading options

```
\usepackage[acronym, section=section, nopostdot, nonumberlist, style=super]{glossaries}
```

and calling

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={Abbreviations}]
\glsaddallunused[\acronymtype]
```

Part of the output is shown below:

[image: glossary page layout]

I would like to perform three changes:

1. <strike>Reduce the vertical space between each group of acronyms</strike>
2. Change the page header to a sans serif font
3. <strike>Fix the flow of the text (page breaks); the last entry on this page doesn't respect the bottom margin.</strike>

I previously tinkered with my LoT and LoF as follows (including the equivalent to point 2 above):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoftables{%                                                                                                                                                         
    \section*{\listtablename}%                                                                                                                                                       
    \@mkboth{\sffamily\normalsize\listtablename}%                                                                                                                                    
    {\sffamily\normalsize\listtablename}%                                                                                                                                        
    \@starttoc{lot}%                                                                                                                                                                 
}
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%                                                                                                                                                        
    \section*{\listfigurename}%                                                                                                                                                      
    \@mkboth{\sffamily\normalsize\listfigurename}%                                                                                                                                   
        {\sffamily\normalsize\listfigurename}%                                                                                                                                       
    \@starttoc{lof}%                                                                                                                                                                 
}
\makeatother
```

but I have no idea how to access the glossary.

---

*EDIT:* points 1 and 3 above solved by removing a spurious `\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}` lying around.

Answer (score 1):

I solved point 2 by using the following

```
\renewcommand{\glsglossarymark}[1]{%                                                                                                                                                 
    \@mkboth{\sffamily\normalsize{#1}}%                                                                                                                                              
        {\sffamily\normalsize{#1}}%                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

Seems to be doing the job.